# Unable to get to newly added functions to print list out after user input

Tags: python-3.x, function

Newbie to coding. Wondering how to insert functions to separate my code into smaller blocks that can in turn loop back to opening prompt. My input is able to be shown, but the printed list of that input afterword is not. Nor is the follow input question to pick a list and print that out.

Tried placing the def function() in various spots along w/ the needed inndentation, wondering if I need to switch where its placed or need further statements

```
emp_list_1 = []
emp_list_2 = []
emp_list_3 = []
emp_list_4 = []
emp_list_5 = []


# user instructions to begin creating list
print('Please enter your Employee information in the below prompts')


# user input for list 1
employeeName_1 = str(input('Name: '))
employeeSSN_1 = str(input('SSN: '))
employeePhone_1 = str(input('Phone: '))
employeeEmail_1 = str(input('Email: '))
employeeSalary_1 = str(input('Salary: '))

def employee_input_1(emp_list_1): # list 1 append
    emp_list_1.append(employeeName_1)
    emp_list_1.append(employeeSSN_1)
    emp_list_1.append(employeePhone_1)
    emp_list_1.append(employeeEmail_1)
    emp_list_1.append(employeeSalary_1)
    for count1 in range(0, len(emp_list_1)):
        print(emp_list_1[count1], end=' ')
    print('')

# user input for list 2
employeeName_2 = str(input('Name: '))
employeeSSN_2 = str(input('SSN: '))
employeePhone_2 = str(input('Phone: '))
employeeEmail_2 = str(input('Email: '))
employeeSalary_2 = str(input('Salary: '))
```

def employee_input_2(emp_list_2): # list 2 append
       emp_list_2.append(employeeName_2)
       emp_list_2.append(employeeSSN_2)
       emp_list_2.append(employeePhone_2)
       emp_list_2.append(employeeEmail_2)
       emp_list_2.append(employeeSalary_2)

```
   for count2 in range(0, len(emp_list_2)):
       print(emp_list_2[count2], end=' ')
   print('')

# user input for list 3
employeeName_3 = str(input('Name: '))
employeeSSN_3 = str(input('SSN: '))
employeePhone_3 = str(input('Phone: '))
employeeEmail_3 = str(input('Email: '))
employeeSalary_3 = str(input('Salary: '))

def employee_input_3(emp_list_3): # list 3 append
    emp_list_3.append(employeeName_3)
    emp_list_3.append(employeeSSN_3)
    emp_list_3.append(employeePhone_3)
    emp_list_3.append(employeeEmail_3)
    emp_list_3.append(employeeSalary_3)

    for count3 in range(0, len(emp_list_3)):
        print(emp_list_3[count3], end=' ')
    print('')

# user input for list 4
employeeName_4 = str(input('Name: '))
employeeSSN_4 = str(input('SSN: '))
employeePhone_4 = str(input('Phone: '))
employeeEmail_4 = str(input('Email: '))
employeeSalary_4 = str(input('Salary: '))

def employee_input_4(emp_list_4): # list 4 append
    emp_list_4.append(employeeName_4)
    emp_list_4.append(employeeSSN_4)
    emp_list_4.append(employeePhone_4)
    emp_list_4.append(employeeEmail_4)
    emp_list_4.append(employeeSalary_4)

   for count4 in range(0, len(emp_list_4)):
       print(emp_list_4[count4], end=' ')
   print('')

# user input for list 5
employeeName_5 = str(input('Name: '))
employeeSSN_5 = str(input('SSN: '))
employeePhone_5 = str(input('Phone: '))
employeeEmail_5 = str(input('Email: '))
employeeSalary_5 = str(input("Salary$: "))

def employee_input_5(emp_list_5): # list 5 append
    emp_list_5.append(employeeName_5)
    emp_list_5.append(employeeSSN_5)
    emp_list_5.append(employeePhone_5)
    emp_list_5.append(employeeEmail_5)
    emp_list_5.append(employeeSalary_5)

   for count5 in range(0, len(emp_list_5)):
       print(emp_list_5[count5], end=' ')
   print('')

def list_Counter(all_e_lists):
    all_e_lists = [ ]

    all_e_lists.append(emp_list_1)
    all_e_lists.append(emp_list_2)
    all_e_lists.append(emp_list_3)
    all_e_lists.append(emp_list_4)
    all_e_lists.append(emp_list_5)

#list counter based on amount of lists in all_e_lists
print('There are', len(list_Counter), 'employees in the system.')

def user_emp_choice(): # Next, user request list info
    print("You can pull an individual's list by entering 1 - 5")

    query_emp_list = int(input("Choose 1 - 5: ")) -1
    if 0 <= query_emp_list < len(all_e_lists):
        print(' '.join(all_e_lists[query_emp_list]))
   return
```

Expecting user to input string info, a list of that info is printed out, that repeats 4 more times, then a prompt to choose which list to print out. User can chose an integer from 1-5 to pull said list. Also trying to add in a counter of how many lists in total their are as well, but getting an error that the list/variable is undefined.

Comment: Was able to get the functions working for the initial list creation and user choice at the end. Still trying to figure out how to get it to loop back to the beginning as well as add in a list counter. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just now got the function for looping working for the list choice. Last thing I'm working on is to get the list counter implemented w/ looping as well.